# Obtaining GCC for OSX with Developer Tools installed

Tags: macos, gcc

I want to start working with C++0x. I see that GCC 4.7 has a fair amount of functionality available. I already have XCode 3.2 installed in /Developer

I downloaded: http://fileboar.com/gcc/snapshots/LATEST-4.7/gcc-4.7-20110528.tar.bz2

Can I somehow compile this in /opt/gcc-4.7? How do I then work with my path so I can compile with GCC 4.7 from the command-line but have OSX use the version it needs?

Answer (score 0):

OSX does not need gcc to run - the Developer tools are optional. So you only need to choose between gcc's when you compile. In Xcode you chose explicitly the gcc andin Makefiles you can set $(CC) or similar to the full path.

Alternatively rename the gcc-4.7 gcc to gcc-4.7 and use that so gcc is always the Apple one.

For ease of using multiple C++ compilers I use macports (or fink or homebrew) which will compile the compilers with the correct patches and also has a port select command to switch between the C++ compilers